# Windows Batch:Nested for loop counter not working

Tags: batch-file

I'm a novice at batch and been trying to get this to work properly but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. The counter doesn't increment for some reason?

```
@echo off
set local enabledelayedexpansion

set /a counter=0
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b/ad/o "C:\Sources"') do (
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b/ad/o "C:\Sources\%%a"') do (
set a[%counter]=%%i
set /a counter=counter+1
echo value of counter is: %counter%
)
)
echo array 0 is: %a[0]%
echo array 1 is: %a[1]%
```

Comment: Would you mind telling us what your code should do and what it actually does? We usually don't have crystal balls... And read this: [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)...

Comment: first for loop takes all the folders in a directory and loops through the child folders to assign to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SET LOCAL` should really be `SETLOCAL`.  It's a single command.  Also the nested variables should be refernced with `!var!` and not `%var%`.  If you use `%var%` it will use the outer scope (and not work correctly).

https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html

```
@ECHO OFF

REM "SETLOCAL" not "SET LOCAL"
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

SET counter=0
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,10) DO (
    FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,10) DO (    
        REM USE "!" instead of "%"
        SET  X[!counter!]=%%i
        SET /a counter=!counter! +1
        echo value of counter is: !counter!
    )
)
ECHO array 0 is: %X[0]%
ECHO array 1 is: %X[1]%
```

BTW, if you want to have your variables just scoped to your batchfile you should end your script with `ENDLOCAL`

Comment: the set local was a typo in the question but the ! vs. % made the difference. Appreciate the help! What's the reason for needing ! vs. %?

Comment: The only why I know is `Because, that's just the way it works.`  It seems that's how batch files resolve scope.